# Custom Shape in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, user-experience

I'm trying to draw a shape like this with some text and data in it.

[image: Required Output]

I am using CustomPaint for this

```
CustomPaint(
  painter: new RightBox(context),
  child: container()
),
```

```
 Container container() {
   return Container(
     height: 200,
     width:  200,
     color: Colors.black,
     margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
     child: Center(child: Text("Hi Khushal",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),
         ),)
   );
 }
```

```
class RightBox extends CustomPainter {
  RightBox(this.context);
  BuildContext context;
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    Paint paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black;

    Path path = Path()

      ..moveTo(size.width * 0.02 + size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.85)
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.05 + size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.70)
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.45 + size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.67)
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.48 + size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.85);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RightBox oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image: Output I'm getting with the above code]

I want the text to be shown in the bottom right CustomPaint Widget,
I am passing a child Container to the CustomPaint but instead, I'm getting a widget positioned separately in the stack.
I know I'm doing something wrong, please help me achieve the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `painter` is taking the full size of the screen. Hence, you need to `align` the `container` to put it inside the painter. Here is one way to do it. There are several ways to do it.

You put your `container` and `painter` inside a `stack` widget. `Align` the `container` according to your needs. Make sure to give a few `padding` and `margin` to get a more accurate result.

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
            width: 200,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Hi Khushal",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            )),
      ),
      CustomPaint(
        painter: RightBox(context),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```